# How to change polygon pane in Leaflet (custom pane)

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I figured out how to create a polygon in a custom pane using [the Working with Map Panes tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/map-panes/) and [this Stack Overflow question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/178622/z-index-of-geojsons-and-imageoverlays-in-leaflet/178873#178873) with its associated [Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/nathansnider/4gmqf0ug/).

**Can I switch the polygon to a different (custom) pane after it has been created?**

I create a polygon in a custom pane like so:

```
// create custom pane
mymap.createPane('polygonView');
var polygonViewPane = mymap.getPane('polygonView');
polygonViewPane.style.zIndex = 300;
// with custom renderer 
var myrenderer = L.svg({
  pane: polygonViewPane
});

// create polygon in a custom pane (note the `renderer:myrenderer` or `pane:polygonViewPane` both work)
var myPoly = L.polygon([
  [51.509, -0.08],
  [51.503, -0.06],
  [51.51, -0.047]
], {
  fillOpacity: 1,
  pane: polygonViewPane
}).addTo(mymap);
```

It would seem like I should be able to switch the pane with something like:

```
// changes pane in options.pane, but appearance on the map is same
myPoly.setStyle({pane: polygonViewPaneTop});     
// also does not work (command fails without output in console?)
myPoly.setStyle({renderer: myrenderer2});
```

but neither of these are working.  I can switch the zIndex of the whole pane with `polygonViewPane.style.zIndex = 800;`, but I will usually have multiple polygons on that main pane, and I only want to bring one to the front of all of my layers.

https://jsfiddle.net/kbkxf220/

---

**EDIT:**
Updated Fiddle incorporating IvanSanchez's answer:
https://jsfiddle.net/kbkxf220/3/

```
// THIS WORKS; polygon switches pane and `myPoly.options.pane` shows new pane.
myPoly.removeFrom(mymap);
myPoly.setStyle({pane: polygonViewPaneTop, renderer: myrenderer2}); 
myPoly.addTo(mymap);
```

Note that you need to switch `renderer` for the polygon to switch panes on the map view (see inspect element) and switch `pane` for `myPoly.options.pane` to properly display the new pane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Leaflet doesn't allow to change panes on the fly.

Remove the layer from the map, change its options, then re-add it.

If your problem is bringing lines/polygons on top of each other, remember that you can [call `bringToFront()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#path-bringtofront) on them.

Comment: Thank you for that.  I would also add that `bringToFront()` only sorts within a single renderer (see [L.Path's version of `bringToFront()`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/49213551953067aa70c3c3d2e74a6c5431a896c5/src/layer/vector/Path.js#L110); so if it doesn't seem to be working correctly, check for multiple renderers.  I was using a custom renderer for some layers, but not all.  To sort all path layers together, I needed to use the same renderer on all path layers.  Took me a while to figure that one out... :)